# Android WebServices with ksoap2

Tags: android, web-services, wsdl, android-ksoap2

i have a wsdl file it the website and i would like to get some services.
My question is: how to find those parameters:

```
SOAP_ACTION
METHOD_NAME
NAMESPACE
URL
```

Here is my code but I have the connexion problem:

```
public class TestBookSoapActivity extends Activity {

private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://api.mdpi.com/ws/GetVersionInfo";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetVersionInfo";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://api.mdpi.com/ws/";
private static final String URL = "http://api.mdpi.com/ws/mdpi.wsdl";


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    executeAppelSOAP();

}
private void executeAppelSOAP() {
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("arg0", "10");


    SoapSerializationEnvelope enveloppe = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    enveloppe.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport (URL);             
    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, enveloppe);
        Object resultat = enveloppe.getResponse();
        System.out.println("Version = " + resultat.toString());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Problem");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Soap-Ui  http://www.soapui.org/  to get answers to your problem. Then modify your android code accordingly...

Comment: Thanks, but I have allready the SoapUi but I don't know where i have to look for those informations. Could you give me an example please?

Comment: hmm do one thing ... I used the same technique an some time back.. I guess there is one raw (view) for soaps(xml) request and response. Go through it by few trials you will get the actual values for your variables. Also try to integrate a sample web services from w3schools in Soap UI and check the response and request.